# Iterating Variadic Macro Arguments

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I am programmatically generating bunch of functors, in order to keep the generated code more readable I am trying to come up with a macro that will expand line the following,

```
SET_STATE(FunctorA,a,b);

ref a;
ref b;
FunctorA(ref a, ref b){
   this->a = a;
   this->b = b;
}
```

Basically it will expand to the first arguments constructor. Variadic part is the number of arguments to the constructor. is it possible to loop inside the macro and generate this code during preprocessing even though it does not make sense for this particular case but I have some functors that have 20 or so variables that they have access to it will cleanup my generated code a lot.

All arguments will be of the same type, only names will differ.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but have you considered something like `class FunctorA { public: struct FunctorAParams{ ref A; ref B; ... }; FunctorA(const FunctorAParams &params) : params(params) {} private: const FunctorAParams params; };`.

Comment: There's [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html), but I can't type this up OTOH. :)

Comment: is the "ref a; ref b; about the subroutine declaration part of the macro output?

Comment: yes they belong to the functor.

Comment: is there a particular platform this should work on?

Comment: I using this on regular gcc and avr-gcc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the tricked found in this link http://cplusplus.co.il/2010/07/17/variadic-macro-to-count-number-of-arguments/ to count the number of arguments and using some really ugly macro I can generate the output you wanted.

I tested it using **gcc** (gcc -E test.cpp) and it works, *It's not portable*.

Code:

```
#define VA_NARGS_IMPL(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,N,...) N
#define VA_NARGS(...) VA_NARGS_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
#define SET_STATEGENERATE(name, count, ...)             \
        dec ## count (__VA_ARGS__)                      \
        name(ref ## count (__VA_ARGS__)) {              \
            con ## count (__VA_ARGS__)                  \
        }
#define SET_STATEP(name, count, ...) SET_STATEGENERATE(name, count, __VA_ARGS__) 
#define SET_STATE(name, ...) SET_STATEP(name, VA_NARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)
/* args */
#define dec1(a) ref a;
#define dec2(a,b) dec1(a) ref b;
#define dec3(a,b,c) dec2(a, b) ref c;
#define dec4(a,b,c,d) dec3(a,b,c) ref d;
#define dec5(a,b,c,d,e) dec4(a,b,c,d) ref e;
#define dec6(a,b,c,d,e,f) dec5(a,b,c,d,e) ref f;
#define dec7(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) dec6(a,b,c,d,e,f)ref g;
#define dec8(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) dec7(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) ref h;
#define ref1(a) ref a
#define ref2(a,b) ref1(a), ref b
#define ref3(a,b,c) ref2(a,b), ref c
#define ref4(a,b,c,d) ref3(a,b,c), ref d
#define ref5(a,b,c,d,e) ref4(a,b,c,d), ref e
#define ref6(a,b,c,d,e,f) ref5(a,b,c,d,e), ref f
#define ref7(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) ref6(a,b,c,d,e,f), ref g
#define ref8(a,b,c,d,e,f,g, h) ref7(a,b,c,d,e,f,g), ref h
#define con1(a) this->a = a;
#define con2(a,b) con1(a) this->b = b;
#define con3(a,b,c) con2(a,b) this->c = c;
#define con4(a,b,c,d) con3(a,b,c) this->d = d;
#define con5(a,b,c,d,e) con4(a,b,c,d) this->e = e;
#define con6(a,b,c,d,e,f) con5(a,b,c,d,e) this->f = f;
#define con7(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) con6(a,b,c,d,e,f) this->g = g;
#define con8(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) con7(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) this->h = h;
```

So the following:

```
/* 2 args */
SET_STATE(FunctorAA, foo, bar)
/* 3 args */
SET_STATE(FunctorBB, foo, bar, baz)
/* 4 args */    
SET_STATE(FunctorCC, foo, bar, baz, qux)
```

will produce:

```
ref foo; ref bar; FunctorAA(ref foo, ref bar) { this->foo = foo; this->bar = bar; }
ref foo; ref bar; ref baz; FunctorBB(ref foo, ref bar, ref baz) { this->foo = foo; this->bar = bar; this->baz = baz; }
ref foo; ref bar; ref baz; ref qux; FunctorCC(ref foo, ref bar, ref baz, ref qux) { this->foo = foo; this->bar = bar; this->baz = baz; this->qux = qux; }
```

*Note:* you can continue the number of arguments following the obvious pattern.

Comment: what part of it is not portable?

Comment: `__VA_ARGS__` is a C99 extension and as such might or might not be implemented in a C++ compilers preprocessor.

Comment: @Hamza Yerlikaya I updated my code so the number of arguments is not needed, using some trick from the link (in my answer).

Comment: I stated the solution is NOT portable and only known to work for GCC.

Comment: Did not test it myself, but I think this page suggests otherwise re MSVC: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415.aspx

Comment: @ysap That's VS13; it's possible they have improved since I wrote it 2 years ago. I don't use Windows so I can't test it.

Answer (score 15):

If `boost::preprocessor` and `SEQ` representation(`(a)(b)...`) are allowed,
probably the following code will meet the purpose:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/punctuation/comma_if.hpp>

#define DEF_MEMBER( r, data, elem ) ref elem;
#define DEF_PARAM( r, data, i, elem ) BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF( i ) ref elem
#define DEF_ASSIGN( r, data, elem ) this->elem = elem;

#define SET_STATE( f, members )                         \
  BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH( DEF_MEMBER,, members )         \
  f( BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I( DEF_PARAM,, members ) ) { \
      BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH( DEF_ASSIGN,, members )     \
  }

SET_STATE(FunctorA,(a)(b))
```

The above code is expanded to

```
ref a; ref b; FunctorA( ref a , ref b ) { this->a = a; this->b = b; }
```

in my environment.

Comment: @Xeo:
Thanks! :-) Possibly the dependence on boost might be heavy for the OP
though...

Comment: Boost may be quite loosely coupled. For example, I doubt the Boost.Preprocessor library depends on much, so it should definitely be possible to extract the required files if necessary.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Thank you for pointing out.
As you mentioned, `Boost.Preprocessor` seems to have high modularity.
Probably extracting only `boost/preprocessor` directory will be sufficient
to use it instantly.

Comment: Boost.Preprocessor is designed to work with C only compilers as well as C++ compilers. Its the only C library in boost, I believe.

Comment: I was able to successfully adapt this code and only include the preprocess library of Boost.