# Is constexpr supported with lambda functions / expressions?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, constexpr

```
struct Test
{
  static const int value = []() -> int { return 0; } ();
};
```

With gcc-4.6 I get something like, `error: function needs to be constexpr`. I have tried multiple combinations of putting `constexpr` at various places, but no luck.

Is `constexpr` supported for lambda functions as well (irrespective of `return` type specified or not) ? What is the correct syntax ?

Any work around possible ?

Comment: Under what circumstances would a `constexpr` lambda function be useful? It seems to me like it would only end up adding another pair of braces around the actual expression

Comment: @bdonlan, I have a use case for that (to calculate number of `__VA_ARGS__` in macro). But explaining that will be a whole new question.

Comment: Also see [Why are lambda expressions not allowed in an unevaluated operands but allowed in the unevaluated portions of constant expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22232164/1708801)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Update**: As of C++17, lambdas are permitted in constant expressions.

---

Lambdas are currently (C++14) not allowed in constant expressions as per [expr.const]/(2.6), but they will once [**N4487**](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4487.pdf) is accepted (which can be found in the working draft N4582):

> This proposal suggests allowing *lambda-expressions* in constant
>   expressions, removing an existing restriction. The authors propose
>   that certain *lambda-expression*s and operations on certain closure
>   objects be allowed to appear within constant expressions. In doing so,
>   we also propose that a closure type be considered a literal type if
>   the type of each of its data-members is a literal type; and, that if
>   the `constexpr` specifier is omitted within the lambda-declarator, that
>   the generated function call operator be `constexpr` if it would satisfy
>   the requirements of a `constexpr` function (similar to the
>   `constexpr` inference that already occurs for implicitly defined
>   constructors and the assignment operator functions).

Comment: I suppose making lambdas `constexpr` is a necessary step towards making STL algorithms `constexpr` as well since STL algorithms frequently take lambdas as arguments. Many (all?) of them were indeed made `constexpr` in C++20.

Comment: @AnthonyD973 constexpr-ification of the library is indeed a major overhaul and will likely be extended to the vast majority thereof.

Answer (score 29):

From the C++0x FDIS §7.1.5[dcl.constexpr]/1:

> The `constexpr` specifier shall be applied only to the definition of a variable, the declaration of a function or function template, or the declaration of a static data member of a literal type.

A lambda expression is none of those things and thus may not be declared `constexpr`.

Comment: Workaround for what?  What are you trying to accomplish with a `constexpr` lambda expression?  Why can you not use an ordinary function or function template?

Comment: I am able to calculate number of `__VA_ARGS__` of macro at run time using lambda expression. Just making it `constexpr` will be a compile time constant. Explaining that will be a detailed new topic. I know that there are `boost` alternatives available, but the method I have used seems to me very straight forward and handy.

Comment: Why not just use a `VA_NARGS` and do the computation at preprocessing (see the example [at the beginning of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194031/iterating-variadic-macro-arguments/6194669#6194669)).

Comment: Or how about using variadic templates and `sizeof...()`? Something like `template<typename... Args> Counter { static const size_t N = sizeof...(Args); };`, and then use `Counter<a,b,c>::N`, if your macro arguments are types... or something more elaborate with `constexpr size_t f(Args... args) const { return sizeof...(Args); }` if your arguments aren't types.

Comment: In general since preprocessor macros expand where they're used and can't go back and declare functions somewhere earlier, lambdas give them a lot of added power. If lambdas worked with constexpr, then that power could be applied to template arguments. I don't know to what end, but it seems potentially very powerful. And now it's a new annoying C++ inconsistency to remember. Lambda functions can do what regular functions can oh except constexpr :P

Comment: Is this still true in C++14?

Comment: @JosephGarvin yes. Variable templates were added to the things that can be `constexpr` but nothing regarding lambdas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As we are moving closer towards C++17, I am accepting another (year old) post for the future visitors. I notice that another good answer posted today which suggests relevance of lambda & `constexpr` relation.

Answer (score 20):

**Prior to C++17** lambdas are not compatible with `constexpr`. They cannot be used inside *constant expressions*.

**Starting with C++17** lambdas are `constexpr` where it makes sense. The proposal [N4487](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4487.pdf) will be put into the C++17 standard. On [his website](https://herbsutter.com/2016/06/30/trip-report-summer-iso-c-standards-meeting-oulu/) Herb Sutter, chair of the ISO C++ committee, stated the following:

> Lambdas are now [allowed inside constexpr functions](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/P0170R1.pdf).

Answer (score 13):

FFWD to year 2018 :)

```
auto my_const_expression_lambda = []()
  constexpr -> bool
{
   return true ;
}
```

Since c++17

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but no one specified a workaround for this.  The workaround is to use a `constexpr` functor like so:

```
struct functor
{
    constexpr int operator()() { return 0; }
};

struct Test
{
  static const int value = functor{}();
};
```

Not optimal as it moves the code away from where it's used, but when you don't have many options, this is doable.  I had to use something similar for a project still compiling with c++14.  This simple case has been tested on c++11 here:  https://godbolt.org/z/Gvxq19jsd

However, if you have c++17 or higher, using the described:

```
struct Test
{
  static constexpr int value = []() constexpr { return 0; }();
};
```

is a nicer option.