# Confusion with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, memory-management, unique-ptr

I would expect the following code to crash at runtime with a null pointer error:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

struct Foo {
    void echo() {std::cout << "Echo" << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> up(new Foo());
    up.reset(nullptr);

    assert(up.get() == nullptr);

    up.get()->echo();
}
```

however both gcc (4.7/4.8/4.9), msvc (2013 and upcoming 2015) and clang (3.5) happily outputs:

```
Echo
```

and assert is not firing so `up.get()` is `nullptr`.

Comment: UB is UB, you should not expect anything.

Comment: How can I call a method on a nullptr?

Comment: Finally found the duplicate again.

Comment: @Deduplicator nice work :)

Comment: BTW: The `unique_ptr` is a red hering in your question.

Comment: @Deduplicator well I get that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially calling a member function with an invalid object argument - which is generally considered to trigger undefined behavior. However, you are not using `this` inside the member funtion, so no Segfaults should occur practically.

Try adding a member and accessing that member inside `echo`. That should crash your program. I.e.

```
struct Foo
{
    int i;
    void echo() {std::cout << i << std::endl;}
};
```

Comment: The error is earlier, see the duplicate.

Comment: @Deduplicator What do you mean? Dereferencing a null pointer? dyp says otherwise. I've used the same argumentation myself some time ago.

Comment: @Columbo: Dyp says dereferencing a null-pointer *in C++* is fine? Where, and what are his arguments? I hope it's not "it seems to work". Because I would be *very* interested in anything allowing dereferencing null-pointers, especially as it breaks the guarantee that references always represent an object.

Comment: Dereferencing a null-pointer yields an lvalue. No reference is created per se. I'll find the comment where we had the discussion.

Comment: @Deduplicator I mixed it up a little bit. [**Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168164/lambda-expressions-as-class-template-parameters-in-c14#comment41046731_26170459) are the comments. Also consider hvd's last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Calling member function through NULL pointer is surely an undefined behavior.

Your call to that member function is successful as you are not making use of this pointer.