# Evaluated constexpr lambda in non-type template argument

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, sfinae, c++17

Lambda expressions are not allowed in unevaluated contexts (e.g. in decltype) and could not be constant expressions until recently. Therefore there was no way to use them in template arguments.

In C++17 however constant expression lambdas will be possible. This still does not allow using them in template arguments in general.

However specifically for non-type template arguments constant expression lambda expressions could be used in an evaluated context, for example:

```
template<int N> struct S { constexpr static int value = N; };

int main() {
    int N = S<[]()constexpr{return 42;}()>::value;
}
```

That still doesn't work though, because lambda expressions are explicitly disallowed in template arguments whether type or non-type.

My question is the reasoning behind not allowing the construct above. I can understand that types of lambdas in function signatures might be problematic, but here the closure type itself is irrelevant, only the (compile-time constant) return value is used.

I suspect that the reason is that all statements in the lambda body would become part of the template argument expression and consequently SFINAE would need to be applied if any statement in the body is ill-formed during substitution. Probably that would require significant work from compiler developers.

But that is actually my motivation. If it was possible to use the construct above then SFINAE could be used not only with constant expressions, but also other statements valid in constexpr functions (e.g. literal type declarations).

Besides impact on compiler writers, is there any problem this would cause, e.g. ambiguities, contradictions or complications in the standard?

Comment: I think you answered your own question.

Comment: Well, +1 @Barry and this is an interesting Q/A actually.

Comment: @Barry I slightly modified my question. I hoped for some validation that this is indeed the (only) major reason, maybe some reference to a committee paper/discussion mentioning the reasoning.

Comment: *"SFINAE would need to be applied if any statement in the body is ill-formed during substitution"* I'm not sure if that's a concern - SFINAE is only in the immediate context, and one could conceivably interpret the body of the lambda as not immediate.

Comment: `constexpr auto f=[]()constexpr{return 42;};` on previous line then call `f()` makes your argument not make sense.

Comment: @dyp Yes that might be true. But then I am even more suprised that the construct is not allowed, because it would then be identical to assigning the lambda to a variable first and then calling it in the template argument.

Comment: @Eichhörnchen I would have guessed that they're not allowed in template *parameters* (as opposed to arguments), but I'll look that up now.

Comment: @Yakk I am not sure I understand you. I would guess that your variation would be valid C++17 code, though the recent gcc does not accept it. But I am questioning why this intermediate step is explicitly made necessary.

Comment: @dyp The relevant phrase is in [expr.prim.lambda/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#3) I think: "A _lambda-expression_ shall not appear [...] in a _template-argument_ [...]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite intentional that lambdas do not appear in unevaluated contexts. The fact that lambdas always have unique types leads to all sorts of issues.

Here are a few examples from a [comp.lang.c++ discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.c++.moderated/J9MbhcOrAzY/XjKeWEbU1EcJ), from Daniel Krugler:

> There would indeed exist a huge number of use-cases for allowing lambda
>   expressions, it would probably extremely extend possible sfinae cases
>   (to include complete code "sand-boxes"). The reason why they became
>   excluded was due to exactly this extreme extension of sfinae cases (you
>   were opening a Pandora box for the compiler) and the fact that it can
>   lead to problems on other examples as yours, e.g.
>
> ```
> template<typename T, typename U>
> void g(T, U, decltype([](T x, T y) { return x + y; }) func);
> ```
>
> is useless, because every lambda expression generates a unique type, so
>   something like
>
> ```
> g(1, 2, [](int x, int y) { return x + y; });
> ```
>
> doesn't actually work, because the type of the lambda used in the
>   parameter is different from the type of the lambda in the call to `g`.
>
> Finally it did also cause name-mangling issues. E.g. when you have
>
> ```
> template<typename T>
> void f(T, A<sizeof([](T x, T y) { return x + y; })> * = 0);
> ```
>
> in one translation unit but
>
> ```
> template<typename T>
> void f(T, A<sizeof([](T x, T y) { return x - y; })> * = 0);
> ```
>
> in another translation unit. Assume now that you instantiate `f<int>`
>   from both translation units. These two functions have different
>   signatures, so they must produce differently-mangled template
>   instantiations. The only way to keep them separate is to mangle the
>   *body* of the lambdas. That, in turn, means that compiler writers have
>   to come up with name mangling rules for every kind of statement in the
>   language. While technically possible, this was considered as both a
>   specification and an implementation burden.

That's a whole bundle of problems. Especially given that your motiviation of writing:

```
int N = S<[]()constexpr{return 42;}()>::value;
```

can be easily solved by instead writing:

```
constexpr auto f = []() constexpr { return 42; }
int N = S<f()>::value;
```

Comment: Of course now that I posted this, I also found [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22232164/2069064).

Comment: I don't quite understand what's the problem with template arguments, though: they're not part of the signature, and why should SFINAE apply to the lambda body?

Comment: @dyp SFINAE is secondary to actually having lambdas there in the first place. I don't think that matters.