# Lambda in branch not taken of constant expression: Who is right?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, language-lawyer

I tried to compile the following C++11 code with mixed results.

```
struct NoTemplate {
    static constexpr auto (*foo)() = false ? +[]{} : nullptr;
};

NoTemplate no_inst;


template<typename>
struct YesTemplate {
    static constexpr auto (*foo)() = false ? +[]{} : nullptr;
};

YesTemplate<float> yes_inst;
```

- clang: Compiles `NoTemplate` sucessfully; gives `error: a lambda expression may not appear inside of a constant expression` on `YesTemplate`.
- gcc: Compiles both successfully
- msvc: Crashes.
- icc: Crashes (we have a winner!)

What is the correct result? I see some standard language suggesting non-constant expressions should be OK in the false branch of short-circuiting operators in constant expressions, but IANALL.

Comment: By crashes do you mean the compiler crashes or the program crashes?

Comment: In the latest VC (19.12.something) with the standard set to c++17 and warnings set to level 4 I get ambiguous operator on the '+'

Comment: Looks like a clang bug, clang HEAD does not provide a diagnostic [see it ive](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2I7TE8WOTzZvmeZC) the language [supports lambdas in unevaluated portion of conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22232164/1708801)

Comment: @user4581301 Compiler crashes.

Comment: Well, we can definitely say compiler crashes are always a bug and never intended behavior. :) Nice job finding multiple crashes though.

Comment: What is `+[]{}`?

Comment: @asimes unary `operator+` on the lamdba that effectively converts it to a function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This program is well-formed.

Note after C++17, a lambda expression may be accepted in a core constant expression even if it would be evaluated. You can see the proposed paper [N4487](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4487.pdf) for detail.