# Static array of lambda functions (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'd like to do something like this (inside a class):

```
static constexpr MyStruct ops[6] = {
    {'+', [&] (double a, double b) { return a+b; } },
    {'-', [&] (double a, double b) { return a-b; } },
    ...
};
```

Where `MyStruct` is defined as:

```
typedef double (*binOp)(double, double);
struct MyStruct {
    char c;
    binOp fn;
};
```

I also tried:

```
std::function <double(double,double)> fn;
```

for the definition of `fn`, but no luck.

The error I get for the first case is *"error: field initializer is not constant"* which I don't really get. If I try with `std::function` it gets worse, since it says: "cannot be initialized by a non-constant expression when being declared".

Why is the lambda function non-constant? Am I missing something?

Comment: Replace `constexpr` with `const`.

Comment: lambda-expressions currently may not occur inside constant expressions, but that restriction might get removed eventually: https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4487.pdf

Comment: From C++17, please note that lambdas can now be constexpr:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420085/is-constexpr-supported-with-lambda-functions-expressions

Comment: Also note your lambda's capture everything in their scope by reference. Currently they don't use anything so it's not a problem, but capturing lambda's are not convertible to a raw function pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you construct `constexpr` object, everything you pass into it needs to be a core constant expression, [decl.constexpr]/9:

> A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as `const`. Such an object shall have
>   literal type and shall be initialized. If it is initialized by a constructor call, **that call shall be a constant expression** (5.19).

and, from [expr.const] lambdas are not constant expressions<sup>1</sup>:

> A *conditional-expression* *e* is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of *e*, following the rules of the
>   abstract machine (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - [...]
> - a lambda-expression (5.1.2);
> - [...]

However, that applies only to `constexpr` and not to `const`, so you could simply do that instead:

```
static const MyStruct ops[6] = {
    {'+', [] (double a, double b) { return a+b; } },
    {'-', [] (double a, double b) { return a-b; } },
};
```

Note: your lambdas don't need to capture anything, so you should just empty the capture list `[]`.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>As [dyp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527865/static-array-of-lambda-functions-c/30528095#comment49129482_30527865) points out, there is a proposal to change this: [N4487](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4487.pdf)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

capturing lambda cannot decay to function pointer.

and operator to return the function pointer from a (non-capturing) lambda is not `constexpr`.