# Initializing constexpr variable by a lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, constexpr

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

constexpr auto fx = [] (std::string msg) {
  return msg + "!\n"; };

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc == 2)
    std::cout << "hello " << fx(argv[1]);
  else
    std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl;
}
```

Command

```
$ g++ -o hello -std=c++11 hello.cpp
```

gives

```
hello.cpp:4:21: error: constexpr variable 'fx' must be initialized by a constant expression
constexpr auto fx = [] (std::string msg) {
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

g++ version:

```
$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

On gcc version 5.2.1 (linux) compiles without any issues.

Comment: Check out the second answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420085/is-constexpr-supported-with-lambda-functions-expressions). It seems like this change has to do with the adoption of N4487.

Comment: I *like* the g++ version -> clang.

Comment: So gnu's g++ has wrong behaviour? clang gives expected fail?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the lambda:

```
constexpr auto fx = [] (std::string msg) { return msg + "!\n"; }**()**;
```

Comment: The context doesn't support this interpretation (and you'd need an argument and C++20 for that anyway).