# Product of functions with a fold expression

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, constexpr, c++17, fold

I want to write a function which takes an arbitrary number of functions of the form `float(float, float)` and yields a callable object (e.g. a lambda expression) which represents the product (in the mathematical sense) of these functions.

We can do this, for example, in the following way:

```
template<typename... BinaryFunctions>
auto product_of(BinaryFunctions... fs) {
    return [=](float x, float y) { return (... * fs(x, y)); };
}
```

However, until C++17, the returned lambda is not a `constexpr` even when the `fs` are. So, the question is: I want to keep the fold expression, but how can I modify `product_of` such that the returned callable object is a `constexpr` in the sense of C++14?

Comment: Fold expressions are C++17 only. Are you asking how to replace the fold expression and have `constexpr`-ness in C++14?

Comment: Also you probably want `[=]`, not `[&]`...

Comment: @VittorioRomeo No, I want t to keep the fold expression, but achieve the `constexpr`ness in the sense of C++14.

Comment: @Barry Thank your for noting that.

Comment: You never *have* to use lambda expressions. You're always more than welcome to create your own functor type, which can be just as constexpr as you care to make it.

Comment: @KerrekSB What do you suggest?

Comment: It looks like when compilers fully support C++ 17, you'd be able to do this simply: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38848385/1896169 . `[=](float x, float y) constexpr { return (... * fs(x, y)); };`

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Write your own functor template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to bend over backwards to use a fold expression, you can still do it. You will need an auxiliary function class:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<typename... Fs>
class product_of_fn
{
    std::tuple<Fs...> fs;
public:
    template<typename... FsFwd>
    constexpr explicit product_of_fn(FsFwd &&... fs)
        : fs{ std::forward<FsFwd>(fs)... }
    {}

    constexpr auto operator()(float x, float y) {
        return impl(x, y, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Fs)>{});
    }
private:
    template<std::size_t... Is>
    constexpr auto impl(float x, float y, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return (... * std::get<Is>(fs)(x, y));
    }
};
```

Usage (using [@VittorioRomeo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43243060/1896169)'s example)

```
template<typename... Fs>
constexpr auto product_of(Fs... fs) {
    return product_of_fn<std::decay_t<Fs>...>{ std::forward<Fs>(fs)... };
}

template<int>
struct adder
{
    constexpr auto operator()(float x, float y) { return x + y; }
};

int main()
{
    auto f = product_of(adder<0>{}, adder<1>{});

    static_assert(f(1, 2) == 3 * 3);
}
```

The idea is pretty much exactly the same as Vittorio's, except we use a `std::tuple` so that we can use the `product_of` function with function objects whose types are `final`, as well as multiple functions of the same type.

A `std::index_sequence` is used to re-obtain a parameter pack just so that we can do a fold expression.

---

Simply converting Vittorio's solution works as well, but with the caveats I mentioned (none of `Fs` can be final or the same):

```
#include <utility>

template<typename... Fs>
class product_of_fn : Fs...
{
public:
    template<typename... FsFwd>
    constexpr explicit product_of_fn(FsFwd &&... fs)
        : Fs{ std::forward<FsFwd>(fs) }...
    {}

    constexpr auto operator()(float x, float y) {
        return (... * static_cast<Fs &>(*this)(x, y));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use *fold expressions*, it means that your compiler supports C++17. If your compiler supports C++17, *lambda expressions* are implicitly `constexpr` where possible. I'm assuming that you need a C++14 solution.

---

Just remember that *lambda expressions* are just syntactic sugar for *function objects* with overloaded `operator()`.

Here's a C++14 solution that uses `initializer_list` for the variadic expansion.

```
template <typename... TFs>
struct product_of_fn : TFs...
{
    template <typename... TFFwds>
    constexpr product_of_fn(TFFwds&&... fs) : TFs(std::forward<TFFwds>(fs))... { }

    constexpr auto operator()(float x, float y)
    {
        std::initializer_list<float> results{static_cast<TFs&>(*this)(x, y)...};
        float acc = 1;
        for(auto x : results) acc *= x;
        return acc;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
template<int>
struct adder
{
    constexpr auto operator()(float x, float y){ return x + y; }
};

template<typename... TFs>
constexpr auto product_of(TFs&&... fs) {
    return product_of_fn<std::decay_t<TFs>...>(std::forward<TFs>(fs)...);
}

int main()
{
    auto f = product_of(adder<0>{}, adder<1>{});

    static_assert(f(1, 2) == 3 * 3);
}
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/R269r9ofQzppmRK3)

Comment: My compiler is the one shipped with Visual Studio 2017. As many other compilers, MSVC only partially supports C++17 until now. So, as I've written in the question, I want to keep the fold expression, but achieve `constexpr`ness in the sense of C++14 (since MSVC doesn't support `constexpr` lambdas).

Comment: @0xbadf00d I don't understand the obsession with fold expressions that you want to bend over backwards to do it.

Comment: @Vittorio Why do you derive from the functions? Why not use a `std::tuple`? It just seems like a defect to me - you can't have final function objects and you can't use the same function class twice.

Comment: @Justin empty base optimization I'd guess.