# Static array size determined from template values

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to use static array which size needs to be determined by given template values. However size will be constant across program runtime - thats why I decided not to use `std::vector`.

```
template<uint32_t BAR_WIDTH>
class Bar 
{
//do_stuff...
Foo mapper[ [&]()->int{ uint32_t tmp = BAR_WIDTH / Foo:FOO_EDGE; return (BAR_WIDTH % 10 == 0) ? tmp : tmp + 1; }; ];
};
```

`FOO_EGDE` is const static value. IDE gives me a hint that

> Array size expression must have an integer type instead of int(*)()

I wonder if I can make it work this way without using `std::vector`. Any advice is welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem - your array size isn't an integer, it's a lambda taking no arguments and returning `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you are using a lambda for determining the size of the array. If you leave it off and just use the ternary operator, it works:

```
int main() {
    const bool z = true;
    const int x = 5, y = 3;
    int arr[z ? x : y];
    return 0;
}
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/ovWNmZ)

As opposed to:

```
int main() {
    const bool z = true;
    const int x = 5, y = 3;
    int arr[[&]() -> int { return z ? x : y; }];
    return 0;
}
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/aN9wWR)

Comment: Indeed it works, thank you :) it seems I tried to be too clever.

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420085/is-constexpr-supported-with-lambda-functions-expressions), lambda expressions can't be `constexpr` yet, and you can only declare the size of an array with a `constexpr` value (even then, you are not trying to invoke declared lambda (to invoke it - `()` is required at the end of declaration).

To work around such problem, you could use a private static `constexpr` method, and use the return value of it, for the array size declaration:

```
static constexpr uint32_t GetArraySize ()
    {
    uint32_t tmp = BAR_WIDTH / Foo::FOO_EDGE;
    return (BAR_WIDTH % 10 == 0) ? tmp : tmp + 1;
    }

Foo mapper[GetArraySize ()];
```