# boost::hana::is_valid fails to compile with gcc8 (and more) and --std=c++14

Tags: c++14, language-lawyer, template-meta-programming, boost-hana, gcc7

I use this code with `std=c++14` and `gcc7.3`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/hana/assert.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/equal.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/type.hpp>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

template<class T>
bool foo(T elem)
{
    constexpr auto has_overload_to_string = hana::is_valid([](auto t) -> decltype(to_string(t)) {});
    constexpr bool hasOverloadTo_string = has_overload_to_string(elem);
    return hasOverloadTo_string;
}

int main()
{ 
    std::string elem;
    std::cin >> elem;
    foo(elem);
}
```

And it works fine : [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6zP6cP)

If now I use gcc10.1, I got this error: [demo fail](https://godbolt.org/z/33s5eo)

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'bool foo(T) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]':
prog.cc:41:13:   required from here
prog.cc:27:38: error: temporary of non-literal type 'foo<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::<lambda(auto:1)>' in a constant expression
   27 |      [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto has_overload_to_string =
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:28:21: note: 'foo<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::<lambda(auto:1)>' is not literal because:
   28 |      hana::is_valid([](auto t) -> decltype(to_string(t)) {});
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: note:   'foo<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::<lambda(auto:1)>' is a closure type, which is only literal in C++17 and later
```

---

**My question is** : Is gcc7.3 too permissive with C++14 and `is_valid` works when it shouldn't or gcc8 and more add a bug with C++14 ?

Comment: I have no idea how wandbox manages this, but on godbolt it fals for all versions [>8.0](https://godbolt.org/z/faqfhE). C++17 relaxes restrictions on lambdas so that it compiles again.

Comment: Indeed, I will update my post. Thx for the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with `hana::is_valid`, but the lambda is not valid in a constant expression in C++14.

There is already a good language lawyer answer for this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32697323/800347

Clang also consistently provides an error, so it's clear that previous versions of gcc were incorrect in allowing this.

To workaround this, simply remove the `constexpr` qualifier to your variable declaration.

Comment: Thank, I missed the fact I can use a non-constexpr lambda into a constexpr declaration ! It works well : https://godbolt.org/z/bvEMvK